# Apex Interactive grid's Native HTML date picker display formate (mm/dd/yyyy) are changed to (dd/mm/yyyy) in edit form

Tags: html, datepicker, format, oracle-apex, date-format

I have an issue in interactive grid of oracle apex native html date formate. by default the formate shows (mm/dd/yyyy) but when i click the date picker to feed the date it is changed to (dd/mm/yyyy)?
i want same formate on edit and display cell. kidly help me please.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have no control over this setting. Check the "help" text for the attribute, it explains that this is not possible, since you don't control individual users' browser settings.

*Render using the native HTML input date types, if supported by the browser. When 'Show Time' is off, this renders a 'date' type, when 'Show Time' is on, this renders a 'datetime-local' type. Note: The exact display of these date types is dependent on the browser. Native HTML may be the preferred option when the app is being used on a mobile device.
Please note, when using 'Native HTML', because the native date types are very specific about the date format they require, the item's 'Format Mask' will be automatically set by Oracle APEX, and you will not be able to change it. However this will not be the format displayed to the end user. The end user will see the date in the format appropriate to their current locale.*

Also check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date - it shows exactly the same behaviour. The value in the html tag has a different format than the value in the date picker.